# Pyspark: How to replace a matched string with a value from dictionary using regexp_replace?

Tags: python, pyspark, optimization

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import re

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SubstituicaoDicionario").getOrCreate()

dicionario = {
"palavra1": "substituicao 1",
"palavra2": "substituicao 2",
}

data = \[("Este é um exemplo com palavra1 e palavra2.",)\]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, \["Texto"\])

expressao_regular = "|".join(r"\\b" + re.escape(palavra) + r"\\b" for palavra in dicionario.keys())

df = df.withColumn("Texto_Substituido", F.regexp_replace("Texto", fr"{expressao_regular}", dicionario\[f"{$0}"\]))
df.show(truncate=False)
```

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
File "\<fstring\>", line 1
($0)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|Texto                                     |Texto_Substituido                                     |
+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|Este é um exemplo com palavra1 e palavra2.|Este é um exemplo com substituicao 1 e substituicao 2.|
+------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question.